# how can i outfile a csv file with a new name everytime

Tags: php, mysql

```
$BICostumer=$_POST['CostumerId'];    
date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');
$today =date("Y-m-d_H:i:s");

$sql =$bdd->query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'shared/$BICostume+$today.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED   BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  FROM ListSaving WHERE biid ='$BICostumer';");
```

in this part of the query 'shared/$BICostume+$today.csv' i want the file to be outfiled with 2 variables as a name of the file.
each time i export the file i want to get something like **biide13_03/26/2014_10:25:11.CSV** and next export like
**WFGT34_03/26/2014_11:50:11.CSV**

Comment: `"SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'shared/{$BICostume}{$today}.csv' ..."`  You don't need that `+` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plus sign might be causing issue when used in a file name. Try replacing it with an underscore like:

```
$sql =$bdd->query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'shared/{$BICostume}_{$today}.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED   BY  ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  FROM ListSaving WHERE biid ='$BICostumer';");
```

Edited variable usage inside query after @Rocket Hazmat's warning

Comment: Might wanna wrap variable names in `{}`.  PHP might read the `_` as part of a variable name.

Comment: The thing is that i sql expression is not correct im looking for the correct way to write that query because putting SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'shared/$BICostume+$today.csv' is not correct. my sql is taking this part $BICostume+$today.csv as a string

Comment: Make sure your db user (not the app user) have write permission to shared folder.

Comment: yeah thank you guys the problem is solved and yeah i already made the permission for my folder .